# Moving the same commandButton from one point to another in the same page

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I have a strange problem with commandButton on JSF pages using both primefaces commandButton or XHTML CommandButton. This is my code:

```
<div id="outer">
<h:form>
<p:commandButton action="#{logoutBean.logout}" value="Logout" /> (1)
</h:form>
</div>

<div id="footer">
<h:form>
(2)
</h:form>
</div>

/* these are inherited from upper code ... */
</div>
</div>
```

I want to move(cut&paste) the instruction 1 in the point 2 and delete it from point 1 ... But if I do this, the page falls in error. Why??
I found this problem with every `commandbutton` I have on my project.

How can I do this??? the strange thing is that if I comment the new-line at point 2 (so the program should return working well) it doesn't. To make the program rerun I have to delete literally the newline completely.

Comment: What's the error then? The error represents the whole answer. Ignoring it doesn't help in understanding the answer.

Comment: what are you saying ??? the problem is that i cannot move the instruction from point 1 to point 2 ...

Comment: BalusC is saying that "the page falls in error" is not nearly enough information to come up with a solution. We need facts, figures, error messages!